# How to ignore all the quotes and double quotes in a String in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

i would like to mock a web service response. The response is a XML, and contains both simple quotes and double quotes.

The response is pretty big, so here are my solutions:

- trim the response to make it smaller and backslash the simple quotes for example
- backslash the simple quotes for example
- add the response to a file and parse it

But the thing is, I'd like to test a large response, and not create a resource test folder with a file. And as you can imagine, backslashing everything is long and boring.

I also tried the triple double quote, not working of course.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Ruby [here documents](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents).

```
xml = <<DOC
<xml>
<food attribute="soup">'eel'</food>
</xml>
DOC
```

Comment: If the document happened to contain a "DOC" by itself on a line, this would break. Granted it's unlikely, but it's best to use a longer var such as `xml = <<____MY_DOCUMENT_ENDS_HERE____` to further reduce the possibility of such a thing happening.

Answer (score 3):

use the `%Q` operator

```
a = :jed

%Q| "these double quotes are ignored" for as
    long as you can type says #{a}
  |
```

any start end delimiters work so if you are using tables in cucumber for example you can use backticks instead of pipes

Comment: I like your answer but I think I'd go for Jonas one. I like the fact that people reading my code understand its a document i'm representing! Thank's anyway, i'll use it somewhere else!

Comment: totally a matter of style, either method will be resolved by ruby as a string. good luck!

Comment: If the string has a "|" character, this will fail.

Comment: @mark, which is why i qualified this with 'any start end delimiters work...' `<<` fails too if you give a used set of delimiters that match something in the escaped string.

Answer (score 0):

```
→ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > str = <<-STR
ruby-1.9.2-p0"> ' single quote
ruby-1.9.2-p0"> " double quote
ruby-1.9.2-p0"> STR
 => "' single quote\n" double quote\n" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >
```